# Apache Kafka Connect Route a message based on a record value

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'd like to route a message based on a field value.

I'm using the JDBC connector to pull data from a table like this:

```
id      table       change                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3       dbo.Pets    {"OP":"UPDATE", "Id":"3", "Name":"Rufus","Type":"Cat","Number":"10482638"}
4       dbo.Pets    {"OP":"INSERT", "Id":"", "Name":"Misifu","Type":"Reddy","Number":"85745874"}
```

And I'd like to route each record using the Name json field contained in the change column value. Then, I have to extract the change column value and then, extract the Name value.

In this example, I'd like to:

- Route the first record to the Pets_Name_Rufus topic.
- Route the second record to the Pets_Name_Misifu topic.

But I don't know if It can be done with transformations.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Typically, you partition a single topic by name, not create one topic for each unique value

Comment: Could you provide me a link to see how to partition by key? Also, is it possible to do what I want to do? I think that it is not possible, after reading the JDBC source connector documentation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Partitioning is automatically done for you in the Kafka API

Comment: My point is that what happens for every new pet name? You make a brand new topic every single time? How will that scale?

Comment: I must ensure order per pet name. But I can set the pet name as the record key, then, all records with the same pet name will be delivered to the same partition, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. And order is guaranteed per partition. You can either write your own partitioner and add it to the Connect classpath, or you just leave the defaults. While you're not necessarily guaranteed unique keys in each partition, all events within each will be chronologically ordered, regardless